# Long time to load first connection in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, streamreader, system.net

I'm making a program that connects to a website and downloads XML from it. It then displays the information to the user.

The problem I am having is when I first open the program and start downloading the XML information it takes a really long time. When I load another page from the site with the program still open, it takes about half a second to download. I was wondering if there was any way to avoid this.

I currently use an HttpWebRequest to download the stream and a StreamReader to read it. Then I go through and parse the XML using XLINQ.

Comment: Is the delay only on the first time hitting the XML-serving website -- that is, on subsequent hits does it retrieve the XML quickly?  If so it could be the XML-serving web application's initial start-up delay...

Comment: It also happens with my update server while I'm checking for updates, I also tried just connecting to http://google.com and it still did the same thing. Same results with a WebClient instead of an HttpWebRequest also.

Comment: Oh and also, once I connect to ANY server all the other servers load fast.

Comment: Hmm that sounds really odd, can you ngen your stuff and retest? Also your not running in the debugger are you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the proxy. If you don't have a proxy defined, the `HttpRequest` class will spend time searching for one. Once it has (or hasn't) found one, it will use that information for the life of the application, speeding up subsequent requests.

```
//internally sets "ProxySet" to true, so won't search for a proxy
request.Proxy = null;
```

You can also define this in the .config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy
    enabled="false"
    useDefaultCredentials="false" >
    <proxy/>
    <bypasslist/>
    <module/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Based on what he's said so far this sounds like the best explanation. Curious to see what Christian finds.

Comment: @Rex M: Thanks a lot for this, this issue was driving me crazy and finally got sorted out with this tweak.. +1..

Answer (score 1):

The first time delay can be due to a combination of the following:

1. Time to resolve the server DNS entry
2. Time to download the proxy
   autoconfig script, compile and
   execute it to determine the
   effective proxy
3. network latency from your app to the proxy server (if there is a proxy server in your     environment)
4. network latency from
   the proxy server to the actual
   destination server.
5. The latency on
   the server to serve the XML
   document. If it has to traverse an
   in-memory object representation and
   generate the XML document, that
   might take some time. Also, if it is
   using techniques like
   XML-Serialization to generate the
   document, then depending on how the
   serializer is configured, the first
   call to serialize/deserialize always
   takes a long time, due to the fact
   that an intermediate assembly needs
   to be generated and compiled.
6. Parsing the XML on the client side
   might take time, esp if the XML
   document structure is very complex.
7. If XLinq (like the XMLSerializer)
   generates temp assembly for the XML
   parsing & querying, then the first
   request will take more time than the
   subsequent ones.

To figure out which part is taking time, insert some time logging into your code using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch():

```
// this is the time to get the XML doc from the server, including the time to resolve DNS, get proxy etc.
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("XML download took: " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

timer.Start();
// now, do your XLinq stuff here...
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("XLinq took: " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

You can insert a loop around this, and see what the difference for the various components between the first request and subsequent requests is.

If you find that the difference is in the downloading, and not the querying, then you can investigate further by getting a network sniff using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to do some more research to figure out what part of the request is taking longer on the first pass.  My first instinct says that the DNS request to get the IP address for the domain name you specify is taking longer, because it isn't cached the first time it runs.  It could also be the web server on the other end that has to run some start-up scripts the first time you query it.  You mentioned that the first request takes a long time, but you don't say how long.  Is this causing a big problem that it takes so long to do the first request, or is it just an annoyance?

Comment: See my comments above in reply to Guy Starbuck. As for the how long, it varies but usually anywhere from 15 to 45 seconds. It's not a big problem but it is an annoyance, especially when I port the program to Windows Mobile.

Comment: "15 to 45 seconds" there is virtually no way a DNS lookup is taking that long every time your app starts up.